# AWS CLI, using `--cli-input-json` in a pipeline

Tags: command-line, amazon-web-services

I'd like to use the `aws` command line application in a pipeline, but it doesn't appear to be possible.

A working example is:

```
$ aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://./mytask.json
```

However the following do not work:

```
$ cat ./mytask.json \
    | aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file:///dev/stdin

Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
JSON received:
```

```
$ aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://<(cat ./mytask.json)

Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
JSON received:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went digging... It looks like `aws` will read the indicated file *twice*, using the second dataset for it's operation. Of course, in a pipeline, the second `read()` will get nothing.

I've added a `pipe://` prefix/schema ([commit](https://github.com/attie/aws-cli/commit/b3af357328965117fcc74539f01e167168e8b037)) for use in this situation which will cache the value... I've also made a [pull request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/3209).

Answer (score 12):

Found a workaround for the time being with xargs that is quite clean:

```
cat ./mytask.json \
    | xargs -0 aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json
```

It only adds `xargs -0` and **requires** `--cli-input-json` to be the last argument

Comment: This will work until the JSON becomes too large (admittedly ~2MiB on my system).

Comment: Same experience @Attie. Eventually on Linux systems you get an `E2BIG` error because the size of the command line arguments exceed `ARG_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to pass the JSON as a variable on `--cli-input-json` and inject bash variables too.

So your example should be:

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json "$(cat < ./mytask.json)"
```

In my scenario at hand I have:

1. Either pass a JSON as you would like

   `aws autoscaling start-instance-refresh --cli-input-json "$(cat < ./options.json )"`
2. Or as HEREDOC in order to pass other variables too. (Not requested but may be useful)

```
asg_nominal_name=AutoScalingGroupName

aws autoscaling start-instance-refresh --cli-input-json "$(cat <<JSON
{ 
    "AutoScalingGroupName": "${asg_nominal_name}",
    "Preferences": {
        "InstanceWarmup": 300,
        "MinHealthyPercentage": 100
    }
}
JSON
)"
```

I am not so familiar to explain the why in bash terms.
Feel free.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is the file encoding problem.  Save your file in UTF-8 without BOM, then it will work.

> If you use Sublime Text, then go to File -> Save with Encoding -> UTF-8.

> In VS Code, at the bottom bar of VS Code, you'll see the label "UTF-8 with BOM". Click it to open the action bar and select "Save with encoding". Choose UTF-8 and save the file.